# How to store query name in a variable and use it later?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

My page returns two queries depending on page you are viewing:

QueryA and QueryB

I determine which page you are looking at and then I want to dynamically change my CF code to use the correct query name as such (pesudo-code example):

```
<cfif GetBaseTemplatePath() EQ #ExpandPath('view.cfm')#>
    <cfset QryName = QueryA>
    <cfelseif GetBaseTemplatePath() EQ #ExpandPath('edit.cfm')#>
    <cfset QryName = QueryB>
  </cfif>

<cfoutput> #QryName.Forename# #QryName.Surname# etc etc </cfoutput>
```

Obviously the above doesn't work because QryName is a variable not a stucture. So do I really have to create a structure again to hold the query or is there any easier way to switch the name?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? What's the error? Because based on the info provided - unless I'm missing something - that should work as you want it to.

Comment: Well it says you're trying to use a variable as a structure...

Comment: When you have errors, post the EXACT error (ie: copy and pasted from the screen), including the context (the code snippet it will output, where it identifies exactly what's erroring), and the first few lines of the stack trace.

Comment: oops just realised it was quotes causing the issue :( I had put it as 'QueryA' rather than just QueryA

Comment: Cool. This is a case in point though... had you posted the error messages as per my suggestion above, you'd've had other people's eyes on it, and we would have spotted that immediately. So for next time... ;-) So don't *describe* the error: just post it.

Comment: OK will do cheers Adam

Comment: This process you demonstrated is yet another example of why you really ought to be using an application framework like FW/1 or ColdBox. You probably could have been done by now if you did not continually try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I find that associative array notation is easier to work with in situations like this.

Comment: Just a side note - ALL variables in CF are objects. Your "qryName" above would be variables['qryName'] - if you see what I mean. I see you discovered that you were using quotes though. I hate it when that happens :)

Comment: @ScottStroz If there some discussion area about MVC then I could share my thoughts on it and you'd see why I can't jump right into using it. What I'm trying to do is understand the principles of MVC and make something that works for now.

Comment: On a side note.. you only need to put pound signs around vars that are being out put, or are quoted in some fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to understand what is happening,...,

You had Version 1:

```
<cfset QryName = 'QueryA'>
```

and changed it to Version 2:

```
<cfset QryName = QueryA>
```

Version 1 actually did what you said you wanted to do, copy the name of a query to a variable.  Version 2 created a pointer to the actual query object.  In other words, it "copied the original query by reference".  Had you stuck to your original plan, you could have suceeded.  You would have had to use associative array notation.  Here is some sample code I just ran to make sure it worked before I posted this answer.

```
<cfquery name="abc" datasource="dw">
table event
</cfquery>
<cfset def = "abc">
```

This is eqivalent to your Version 1.  With this new variable, I can do things like this:

```
<cfdump var="#variables[def]#" metainfo="no">
<cfdump var="#variables[def].recordcount#" metainfo="no">
```

Or even this, which is what you were attempting:

```
<cfoutput>#variables[def]['event_name'][1]#</cfoutput>
```

Notice that the letters def are not quoted.  However, if I want to use that variable in a cfoutput tag, I have to quote them:

```
<cfoutput query="#variables['def']#">
#event_name#<br />
</cfoutput>
```

There are situations where this method is more appropriate to the task at hand.  Looking at your question, your's was probably not one of them.

Comment: thanks dan very informative I appreciate you taking the time to explain this!

Answer (score 0):

It works. I had quotes in my code by mistake e.g. `<cfset QryName = 'QueryA'>` which I didn't see.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, it sounds like your root issue is that you're not using an MVC framework.  What query to run and where to send the user is something a controller would handle for you.

Comment: While this is more suitable as a comment, the poster's rep is too low for that.  Normally I upvote in these situations so the person can post comments, but I won't this time, because I disagree with what he said.